# Classification of same rows in 2D numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, classification

Hi i want to classify indexes of same rows in 2D numpy array. Is there any function to do it ?

Something like this : 
 `a= [[1,2,3] , [2,3,4] , [5,6,7] ,[1,2,3] ,[1,2,3] , [2,3,4]]`
then `f(a)` returns same row indexes `[[0,3,4],[1,5],[2]]`

I would appreciate for your solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one to output list of arrays of row indices -

```
def classify_rows(a):
    sidx = np.lexsort(a.T)
    b = a[sidx]
    m = ~(b[1:] == b[:-1]).all(1)
    return np.split(sidx, np.flatnonzero(m)+1)
```

If you need a list of lists as output -

```
def classify_rows_list(a):
    sidx = np.lexsort(a.T)
    b = a[sidx]
    m = np.concatenate(( [True], ~(b[1:] == b[:-1]).all(1), [True]))
    l = sidx.tolist()
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m)
    return [l[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [78]: a
Out[78]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])

In [79]: classify_rows(a)
Out[79]: [array([0, 3, 4]), array([1, 5]), array([2])]

In [80]: classify_rows_list(a)
Out[80]: [[0, 3, 4], [1, 5], [2]]
```